# Как сделать блок резиновым

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как сделать, чтобы главный блок с контентом растягивался по высоте сайта, в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var contentHeight = $(document).height() - 60;

$('#content').css('height', contentHeight);
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum — dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat.[1] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus[2] et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum — dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
    ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.[1] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
    non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit
    amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus[2] et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Вот [здесь посмотрите](http://zvirec.com/view_post.php?id=50).

Урок о том как прижать footer к низу экрана, ну и Ваш вопрос затрагивается.
Удачи.

Ps: Можно с помощью jQuery рассчитать высоту, вот здесь накидал на скорую руку, [посмотри.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/VABtm/22/)

**UPD**: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/WTtQu/31/
Вот, вроде как-то так.

Comment: спасибо, но что-то ничего не помогает = (

Comment: Что именно?

Comment: В примере выше работает?

Comment: ну с jQuery я,  вообще, не разобрался. А первый пример не помог. Ну ставлю min-height:100% и скролл пропадает. А мне нужно что бы было как сдесь - http://honka.ru/poselki/otkryityi_prodaji/

Comment: спасибо большое, буду разбираться. Успехов!

Comment: Пожалуйста, надеюсь, что помог. В Апдейте (в конце ответа), решение Вашей проблемы. Удачи.